# How to reset the vue-form after ajax submission completed

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

### Discription -  vue.js web form validation scenario

The library of vue-form validator used is from 
https://github.com/fergaldoyle/vue-form

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/zfqt4yhq/51/

#### Question:

1. when using dom's form.reset() method couldn't get form reset to the state without error class. what's the correct way to handle the reset form after ajax submittion?
   when u click on the "reset" button, how to restore to init state without validation text appear below & css highlight?
2. In the jsfiddle example , browser console debug mode

   - since one of the condition to remove error class is to make $submitted value to false, yet how to change the $submitted value?

   `<field-messages name="name" show="$touched || $submitted" class="form-control-feedback">
      <div>Success!</div>
      <div slot="required">Name is a required field</div>
   </field-messages>`

   - `var vueformapp = new Vue({ ... });`
   - `vueformapp.$data.formstate.name.$touched = true // = false;`

     - value changed.
   - `vueformapp.$data.formstate.name.$submitted = ture // false;`

     - value won't be changed.
3. Another possible workaround, Is there any CSS hack to achieve reset form in this jsfiddle case.

Comment: Reset function added in latest release:
https://github.com/fergaldoyle/vue-form/releases/tag/4.0.2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like library unfortunately is not resetting fields as per https://github.com/fergaldoyle/vue-form/issues/55

user there suggest you to use:

```
Object.keys(myFormState).forEach(k => {
  if (k[0] == '$') return;
  const field = myFormState[k];
  field._setPristine();
  field._setUntouched();
});
```

to set form as pristine and fields as untouched. Creator says he will add feature on next release.

You could also use vuelidate:
https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-v-methods

which comes with a reset method. BTW in your tests don't forget to rest model like dfsq says

Comment: thanks for the recommendation on other more popular vue-validator.

Comment: BTW, are u able to figure out how to put the above fix code u mentioned into the jsfiddle mentioned above to make this example reset form work? very appreciated.

Comment: @BOBO no, i used this.formState, but it didn't seemed to work, i'm at work now, so i couldn't play too much with it, i'll try to help more later.

Comment: Thanks for the assistant,  rightnow I am able to achieve a dirty reset no highlighting  workaround by CSS and append parent class ,  but not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:
This is how you reset a form after successful submission.

1. use javascript selectors to select the form. Assuming you only have
   one form in the page, this would be ideal.

```
let form = document.querySelector('form');
form.reset();
```

2. If you are using `vee-validate`, you need to reset the validator so that it cannot throw errors.

```
this.$validator.reset()
```

Thast should be all.

Answer (score -5):

custom validation display tag css name hide

```
$('.error').hide();
```

or other option

```
 $('#formname').clearValidation();
```